# iPhone - Retrieving an image from a PACS server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dicom, itk

How can I connects to a PACS server and retrieves a DICOM image (i already have 3rd party library to display the image ). How would I proceed ? What messages would I
send to the PACS server to say "hello PACS I want this image etc" ???

Is there any library available to connect PACS Server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DCMTK](http://dcmtk.org/) is probably the most commonly used library for implementing DICOM applications.  You should look at the source code examples of C-GET (or C-MOVE) written using DCMTK.  [getscu](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/getscu.html) is one such example.

Comment: +1 While getscu is the easiest way to get started retrieving images, for production code I would prefer movescu. Reason: _This snapshot also contains the first version of a new command line tool getscu, which is a C-GET Service Class User based on the **still experimental** DcmSCU class._ [(Source)](http://blog.jriesmeier.com/2011/09/4th-dcmtk-snapshot-361/). Michael, do you have any experience with [GDCM](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=GDCM_Release_2.2.0) and can compare the quality of the network code to that of DCMTK?

Comment: no, I have not tried gdcmnet yet.  Will let you once if I have, hopefully within the next couple of months.

Comment: I tried gdcmnet in July, and I could not get it to c-move the files over.  c-echo and c-find worked fine.  I spent a bit of time on it, but eventually gave up.  could be that there were bugs.  could also be that I had some configuration issues.